# Return current 11-digit timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp

How can I return the current time of the local machine?

Comment: "the timestamp"?  Do you mean the current time?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, current time.  The below answer is great.  Thank you.

Comment: Please update the question to be correct and complete.  Please do not add comments to a question which you own.  Please UPDATE your question and DELETE your comments.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do you mean this: [time.time()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time)?

From the docs:

*Return the time as a floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in UTC*

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1269884900.480978
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any way to not return the decimal digits?

Comment: make it integer by wrapping it in an `int()` call

Comment: If you convert it to int, it will become less specific, since the decimal places will be lost. If you want to maintain the information, but just store it as an integer, consider this solution: `int(str(time.time()).replace('.', ''))`. If the decimal value is `1269884900.480978`, it will output `1269884900480978`

Comment: @EerikSvenPuudist How about cases when the last right-most digits in the fractional part are zeros?

Comment: as @dolphin mentioned, @EerikSvenPuudist's answer could lead to an error by a factor of 10! Adding another string juggle does it: `int(f'{time.time():<19}'.replace(' ', '0')[:18].replace('.', ''))`

Comment: @stevosn Not by a factor of 10, but also 100, 1000, etc. as long as the fractional trailing zeros are optional and not printed. If one wants to preserve the fractional part, just multiply the original float by 10, 100 or whatever is needed, and then cast the result to int. Ensure that your int type has sufficient range for this operation.

Comment: @dolphin Yes, you are right. This is a cleaner solution! Thanks!